# Azure Mobile Services on Local IIS rather than IIS Express

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

OK, I've created an Azure Mobile Services project in Visual Studio 2013.
I run it up as-is, then in the browser I test it by adding a todo item via the simple browser app that seems to get baked into these service projects. It gives me a '201 success' message - brilliant.

I then convert the project from IIS Express to Local IIS as the web host, recompile and try again, and although I get the same smiley face app telling me that everything is OK, when I try and add a todo item I get a 404 error. This is contrary to the Microsoft article that gives these instructions, which clearly says I am able to choose either IIS Express or Local IIS when setting up the project.

My guess is that web.config is missing something when this project runs on the local IIS server.

I'm hoping someone already has a solution before I spend hours trying to work out how to configure IIS for this type of project.

I've already wasted a load of time working through loads of bugs and gotchas with Azure Mobile, and I'm starting to run out of steam - so I'm hoping someone can help me before I go and grab an account at Parse.com

Many thanks in anticipation.

Dean

Answer (score -2):

The easiest approach for your situation might be to just deploy to the cloud, and use that service for your testing. Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 makes it easy to deploy your app and [connect to it for remote debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/03/14/debugging-net-backend-in-visual-studio.aspx). It is a little slower than using a local instance, but you are also assured that there will be no surprises when you eventually go live (since you are live the whole time).

That said, we will investigate the issue you are seeing with using IIS directly. Some things you might want to try on your own:

1. Verify that you can view the web side from your Mac's browser, to make sure that the firewall is letting the requests through.
2. Try using the "Getting Starting" link from the smiley-face page, to see if the REST endpoints are behaving correctly.

Comment: I do a lot of development disconnected (on a train), which is why I need this to work. I managed to find a way to allow IIS express to punch its way out of the VM security environment and expose itself externally. It's far from a great solution

Comment: in response to your suggestions, as I said in my original post I'm getting 404 errors when using the 'getting started' link to post messages